# при перетаскивании DragTarget не получает данные

Tags: flutter, dart

При перетаскивании DragTarget не получает данные. При перетаскивании, например квадрат A заходит в желтый квадрат, но в желтом квадрате, символ А и други не появляются. Вот пример, полный код.

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _str;

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _str = '';
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 Draggable _widDraggable(String text, Color color) =>
  Draggable(

   //данные
   data: text,

   //отображение виджета в начальной точке
   child: Container(
    width: 100.0,
    height: 100.0,
    color: color,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
     text,
     style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18,
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     ),
    ),
   ),

   //отображение виджета во время перетаскивания
   feedback: Container(
    width: 100.0,
    height: 100.0,
    color: color,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
     text,
     style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18,
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     ),
    ),
   ),

   //отображение виджета в начальной точке во время перетаскивания
   //чтобы не оставался виджет в начальной точке во время перетаскивания
   //Container нужно оставить пустым
   childWhenDragging: Container(),

   //вызывается, когда виджет перетаскивается на DropTarget
   //DropTarget ПРИНЯЛ виджет
   onDragCompleted: () {
    setState(() {

    });
   },

   //вызывается, когда виджет перетаскивается на DropTarget
   //DropTarget НЕ ПРИНЯЛ виджет и виджет отбрасывается
   //содержит скорость и смещение
   onDraggableCanceled: (Velocity velocity, Offset offset) {
    setState(() {
     //позиция виджета = смещению виджета

    });
   },

   //вызывается, когда виджет начинают перетаскивать
   onDragStarted: () {
    setState(() {

    });
   },

   //вызывается, когда виджет отбрасывается
   //содержит скорость и смещение
   onDragEnd: (DraggableDetails details) {
    setState(() {

    });
   },

  );

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
     child: _widDraggable('A', Colors.red),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
     child: _widDraggable('B', Colors.green),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topRight,
     child: _widDraggable('C', Colors.blue),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.85),
     child: DragTarget(

      //создание содержимого этого виджета
      builder: (
       BuildContext context,
       //список перетаскиваемых данных, которые будут приняты
       List<String> candidateData,
       //список перетаскиваемых данных, которые не будут приняты
       List<dynamic> rejectedData) {
        return Container(
         width: 150.0,
         height: 150.0,
         color: Colors.amber,
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         child: Text(
          _str,
          style: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 32.0,
           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
           color: Colors.white
          ),
         ),
        );
      },

      //вызывается если данные Draggable совпадают с указанными данными
      //и возвращает true
      onWillAccept: (data) {
       return data == 'A' || data == 'B' || data == 'C';
      },

      //если Draggable перетаскивается на DragTarget и onWillAccept
      //возвращает true, тогда вызывается onAccept
      //здесь данные передаются виджет, возвращаемый builder
      onAccept: (data) {
       setState(() {
        _str = data;
       });
      },

     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указывайте типы данных (в generics тоже), dynamic это зло.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Name App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Name Page'),
        ),
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _str;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _str = '';
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _f1() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  Draggable<String> _widDraggable(String text, Color color) => Draggable<String>(
        //данные
        data: text,

        //отображение виджета в начальной точке
        child: Container(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
          color: color,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //отображение виджета во время перетаскивания
        feedback: Container(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 100.0,
          color: color,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //отображение виджета в начальной точке во время перетаскивания
        //чтобы не оставался виджет в начальной точке во время перетаскивания
        //Container нужно оставить пустым
        childWhenDragging: Container(),

        //вызывается, когда виджет перетаскивается на DropTarget
        //DropTarget ПРИНЯЛ виджет
        onDragCompleted: () {
          setState(() {});
        },

        //вызывается, когда виджет перетаскивается на DropTarget
        //DropTarget НЕ ПРИНЯЛ виджет и виджет отбрасывается
        //содержит скорость и смещение
        onDraggableCanceled: (Velocity velocity, Offset offset) {
          setState(() {
            //позиция виджета = смещению виджета
          });
        },

        //вызывается, когда виджет начинают перетаскивать
        onDragStarted: () {
          setState(() {});
        },

        //вызывается, когда виджет отбрасывается
        //содержит скорость и смещение
        onDragEnd: (DraggableDetails details) {
          setState(() {});
        },
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: _widDraggable('A', Colors.red),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: _widDraggable('B', Colors.green),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: _widDraggable('C', Colors.blue),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.85),
          child: DragTarget(
            //создание содержимого этого виджета
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                //список перетаскиваемых данных, которые будут приняты
                List<String> candidateData,
                //список перетаскиваемых данных, которые не будут приняты
                List<dynamic> rejectedData) {
              return Container(
                width: 150.0,
                height: 150.0,
                color: Colors.amber,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  _str,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              );
            },

            //вызывается если данные Draggable совпадают с указанными данными
            //и возвращает true
            onWillAccept: (String data) {
              print(data);
              return data == 'A' || data == 'B' || data == 'C';
            },

            //если Draggable перетаскивается на DragTarget и onWillAccept
            //возвращает true, тогда вызывается onAccept
            //здесь данные передаются виджет, возвращаемый builder
            onAccept: (String data) {
              print(data);
              setState(() {
                _str = data;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо!